# How to determine whether a point in multiple points?

Tags: polygon, interpolation, circle

I generate lon and lat of a 12 km circle on map following this [link](https://stochasticcoder.com/2016/04/06/python-custom-distance-radius-with-basemap/):

```
def createCircleAroundWithRadius(lat, lon, radiusMiles):
    ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
    latArray = []
    lonArray = []
    for brng in range(0,360):
        lat2, lon2 = getLocation(lat,lon,brng,radiusMiles)
        latArray.append(lat2)
        lonArray.append(lon2)
    return lonArray,latArray

def getLocation(lat1, lon1, brng, distanceInkm):
    lat1 = lat1 * math.pi/ 180.0
    lon1 = lon1 * math.pi / 180.0
    #earth radius
    R = 6378.1 #km

    distanceInkm = distanceInkm/R

    brng = (brng / 90)* math.pi / 2

    lat2 = math.asin(math.sin(lat1) * math.cos(distanceInkm) + math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(distanceInkm) * math.cos(brng))
    lon2 = lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(brng)*math.sin(distanceInkm)*math.cos(lat1),math.cos(distanceInkm)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2))

    lon2 = 180.0 * lon2/ math.pi
    lat2 = 180.0 * lat2/ math.pi

    return lat2, lon2

lon_new = np.arange(112,121,0.01)
lat_new = np.arange(35,44,0.01)
Lon_min =  np.amin(lon_new)
Lon_max =  np.amax(lon_new)
Lat_min =  np.amin(lat_new)
Lat_max =  np.amax(lat_new)

fig = plt.figure(1)
m=Basemap(projection='lcc',llcrnrlat=Lat_min,urcrnrlat=Lat_max,\
  llcrnrlon=Lon_min,urcrnrlon=Lon_max,lat_0=42,lon_0=115,resolution ='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()

memorialStaduimLat = 38
memorialStadiumLon = 116
distanceInkm = 12
c = 'g'

X,Y = createCircleAroundWithRadius(memorialStaduimLat,memorialStadiumLon,distanceInkm)
print (X,Y)
X,Y = m(X,Y)
m.plot(X,Y,marker=None,color=c,linewidth=2)
```

Then I get lon and lat and a [figure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V__0J8vg6JQsU0oI-VtIridA00eMKBTy):

[116.0, 116.0023909748114, 116.00478121808472, 116.00716999850872, 116.00955658522561, 116.01194024805773, 116.01432025773374, 116.01669588611487, 116.01906640642042, 116.02143109345312, 116.02378922382375, .......115.9880597519423, 115.99044341477442, 115.9928300014913, 115.99521878191531, 115.99760902518862]

[38.10779845944043, 38.107782017026, 38.10773269481342, 38.10765050789331, 38.10753548141146, 38.107387650561066, 38.10720706057185, 38.10699376669598, 38.10674783419097,.....38.10753548141146, 38.10765050789331, 38.10773269481342, 38.107782017026]

This circle is one of [pixels](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18fMF3b_GT29ZMZ4JeAhdh_uZulKGVMu0) of satellite. I want to compare my WRF result (3 km resolution) with the satellite data.

So, I plan to interpolate The Weather Research and Forecasting (WRF) Model result to 0.003 degree resolution (~0.3 km) and calculate the average of grids in that circle. But, how to determine whether a point/grid in that circle by Python?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify which GIS software you are using, or if you are doing this without prior art, which software language you are using. The algorithm for determining point in polygon is easily located with a google (it involves a ray trace and counting the intersections). You will have a more difficult time due to the organization of your coordinates as { x0, x1,....,xN, y0, y1,...yN } since the canonical form is {x0,y0, x1,y1,..., xN,yN}. Coding questions here are expected to contain code. Please take the [Tour].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try the haversine formula:

'''
Distance

This uses the ‘haversine’ formula to calculate the great-circle distance between two points – that is, the shortest distance over the earth’s surface – giving an ‘as-the-crow-flies’ distance between the points (ignoring any hills they fly over, of course!).

Haversine formula:  a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 * cos φ2 * sin²(Δλ/2)

c = 2 * atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
d = R * c
where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)

note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions!

R = 6371e3; // metres

rad = math.pi/180

φ1 = lat1  = x

φ2 = lat2 = x1

λ1 = lng1 = y

λ2 = lng2 = y1

Δφ = (lat2-lat1) = a

Δλ = (lon2-lon1) = b

a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
    Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
    Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2)

z = math.sin(a/2) * math.sin(a/2)+math.cos(x) * math.cos(x1) * math.sin(b/2)*math.sin(b/2)

z1 = math.sin(b/2) * math.sin(b/2)+math.cos(y) * math.cos(y1) * math.sin(a/2)*math.sin(a/2)

c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(z), math.sqrt(1-z))

c1 = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(z1), math.sqrt(1-z1))

d = R * c // distance
'''

So, in Python 3.6:

```
def haversine(a, b, x0, x1): # variables from the original dataset

    R = 6371e3 # metres from earth
    z = math.sin(a/2) * math.sin(a/2)+math.cos(x0) * math.cos(x1) * math.sin(b/2)*math.sin(b/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(z), math.sqrt(1-z))
    d = R * c
    #print (d)
    return(d)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used this formula to generate these lon and lat according to [link](https://stochasticcoder.com/2016/04/06/python-custom-distance-radius-with-basemap/) by python. I want to check whether some of the other data (satellite) is located in this "circle".

Comment: so with python you can create a dataframe and loop over the dataset by using the haversine function. hopes this helps.

Comment: FYI: x0 = the firtst latitude value and x1 is de testing value. so for the distance use rad = math.pi/180 where a = (x0 -x1)*rad and b=(y0 - y1)*rad

Comment: This doesn't solve the point-in-polygon problem -- The original origin and distance are not defined and the error due to spherical calculation is likely to be an issue.

Comment: So, I can check if the distance between the center and my data is smaller than 12 km. Is this as same as 'point in polygon'?